# Ubuntu preseed file

Tags: 14.04, preseed

I am working few days on this and I can't find any reasonable solution.

My situation is: I need 2 hard disks on machine(vmware workstation) and one partition (sdb) is for swap and other is for everything else (sda). I don't need raid or lvm. Filesystem is ext3.

My code is:

```
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string root :: 8192 500 8192 ext3 \
$primary{ } $bootable{ } method{ format } \
        format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 } \
    mountpoint{ / } \
. \
4096 90 4096 linux-swap \
    device { /dev/sdb } \
    $primary{ } method{ swap } format{ } \
.
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select root
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

Can someone give me some solution if that is posible?

Thanks,